# Setting a value in v-if block

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do I use v-if to do two things

1. Show The message and 
   2) set `message.hasSublocationOutage` to true.

So if there is an outage show the message and set the flag to true `message.hasSublocationOutage` Or pass true to a method

```
      <div v-if="!subLocation.outageTag.length - 1">
         There is a problem
      </div>
```

Comment: Vue is for views. It should *never* control state by itself - put this functionality inside the script ;)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some inherent flaws in your design, but you can invoke a method that calculates whether or not to display and sets the `message` at the same time.

HTML

```
<div v-if="canShowAndCalculate()">
    There is a problem
</div>
```

JS

```
export default {
    methods: {
        canShowAndCalculate() {
            if (subLocation.outageTag.length - 1) return false;

            // else
            message.hasSublocationOutage = true
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

As Andrey mentioned, this is highly unadvisable.  Having side effects in your conditional logic hides core logic.  Rather, you ***should*** update a boolean condition when your data changes, not the other way around.

As a side note, you could use a computed property like V Sambor suggested for better performance, but that hides the "wrong" implementation even further since computed properties should always be cached and flowing out, whereas you could expect a method to do both, even though in this case it is inadvisable.

Comment: I would never advise such a thing!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a computed method for this is pretty much the same as @David L answer only that this will cache your display result until some related variables changes their values.

```
computed: {
  display() {
    if (this.subLocation.outageTag.length - 1) {
      return false;
    }

    this.message.hasSublocationOutage = true;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then in Html you can do:

```
<div v-if="display()">
    There is a problem
</div>
```